# Matrix doesn't shrink when put in fraction.

Tags: math-mode, fontsize, matrices, superscripts, fractions

This is my minimal example, the problem is the different size of the two x. I would expect the matrix to be shrunken too, but it isn't. Why is this and how is it corrected?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
$\frac{\begin{pmatrix}x\end{pmatrix}x}{2}$
\end{document}
```

**edit**: I just realized: this is not matrix specific. `\underbrace` does it too. seems like the information to be smaller doesn't get through these "frames":

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
$\frac{\begin{pmatrix}x\end{pmatrix}x}{2}e^{\begin{pmatrix}x\end{pmatrix}x}\int_{\begin{pmatrix}x\end{pmatrix}x}$
$\frac{\underbrace{x}x}{2}e^{\underbrace{x}x}\int_{\underbrace{x}x}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: With a little experimenting you could probably do what you want with a `\scalebox` from the `graphicx` package. But how to do this automatically, I don't know...

Answer (score 4):

In this case you can use the `smallmatrix` environment of the amsmath package. Both `x` would have the same size. `smallmatrix` doesn't include delimiters, they have to be added.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\frac{\left(\begin{smallmatrix}x\\y\end{smallmatrix}\right)x}{2}$
\end{document}
```

[image: small matrix]

Comment: add `mathtools` and you will get a delimited version, `psmallmatrix` for example

Comment: i know about smallmatrix but i dont consider this a solution. i expect the stuff to adapt its size depending on context. the single x does it, why not the matrix? what is the rationale of the makers behind this decision? or is it a bug?

Comment: i now tried working with `\smallmatrix` as a means to make stuff smaller, but it has the disadvantage that it raises its contents. so if i use a smallmatrix to make the stuff over an `\underbrace` smaller, it is at the same time further up and doesnt look like the rest any more.

Answer (score 3):

Without having any solid knowledge on the issue, I trust the `amsmath` is doing The Right Thing. But I wanted to share some explorations on size and spacing. Personally, I'd fancy the bigl/r one.

```
$$
  {(x)x\over2} \qquad
  {\left(x\right)x\over2} \qquad
  {{x\choose y}x\over2} \qquad
  {\left({x\atop y}\right)x\over2} \qquad
  {\bigl({x\atop y}\bigr)x\over2} \qquad
  {\pmatrix{x\cr y}x\over2} \qquad
$$
```

[image]